# Taking output of one program into input of another one in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, input, output

Let's say I got two programs: program1 and program2.
I want to take the output of program1, put it into input of program2, then take output of program2 and put it into input of program1 etc.

How should bash script doing this look like?
I've read a lot about pipes and input/output redirection, but I'm still not sure. Is it possible to use one pipe both for input and output of program2, and another one for program2?

I've written something like this:

```
PIPE=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo $PIPE
exec 3<>$PIPE
rm $PIPE 
cat <&3 >&3 &
```

But when I want to run program1 and program2 like this:

```
cat <&3 | ./program1 >&3 &
cat <&3 | ./program2 >&3 &
```

It doesn't work. Any clues what should I do?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: you ran it on the background...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can loop output of a pipeline back to its input using a FIFO.  Here's how.

First, let's create a fifo (named `pipe`):

```
$ mkfifo pipe
```

Let's also, for demonstration purposes, create shell functions to use in the pipeline:

```
$ p1() { while read a; do sleep 0.1; echo "$((a+1))"; done; }
$ p2() { while read b; do echo "$((b+1))"; done | tee /dev/stderr; }
```

Now, let's run them with `p1` feeding its output to `p2` which sends its output to `pipe` which is fed back to the input of `p1`:

```
$ { echo 1; cat pipe; } | p1 | p2 >pipe
3
5
7
9
11
13
^C
```

The loop would go on forever but I terminated it with a ctrl-C first.  `p1` increments its input by one and `p2` increments its input by one.  The output we see comes from the stderr stream of `p2`.

#### How it works

`{ echo 1; cat pipe; }` provides the input to `p1`.  It provides a `1` as a seed value and then supplies whatever it receives from `pipe`.

`p1` works as follows:

```
while read a
do
    sleep 0.1
    echo "$((a+1))"
done
```

It reads from its input, waits 0.1 seconds, and writes an incremented value to its stdout.  The purpose of the short wait is so that the output does not scroll by too fast on the screen.

`p2` works as follows:

```
while read b
do
    echo "$((b+1))"
done | tee /dev/stderr
```

Just like `p1`, it reads from stdin and writes an incremented value to stdout.  So that we can see what's going on on the terminal, this also sends a copy of the output to stderr.